# How to show current date on a jframe title bar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar

I searched for the solution but couldn't find one. I want to show the current date on my jframe title bar. I know how to get current date using java but I need to show it on the title bar. Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()

Comment: I know how to get current date using java. My problem is I need to show it on the title bar.

Comment: @Pappu I don't believe that you "searched for a solution" and couldn't find the way to change the title of a JFrame.

Comment: @DSquare i know how to change it but only using the properties option in netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get current date> use `java.util.Date`

To format the date> use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

To set title for JFRame>

```
JFrame jFrame= new JFrame("title");
```

or

```
jFrame.setTitle("title");
```

So the solution is,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

JFrame jFrame= new JFrame("Current Date: "+dateFormat.format(date));

or 

jFrame.setTitle("Current Date"+dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: I got the solution just before you post it :)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Nidheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23723218/642706) is correct.

## Localizing With Joda-Time

If you want a localized format for the date, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```

Or, if you have a java.util.Date to convert to Joda-Time.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Generate a string representation of the date-time value using a localized format. Use a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object with the Joda-Time [`DateTimeFormat.forStyle`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle%28java.lang.String%29).

```
java.util.Locale locale = new Locale( "fr", "CA" ); // Québécois style.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" ).withLocale( locale );
String output = formatter.print( now );
```